# How to calling a function in a .net dll through an interface loaded through reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

Hello I'll try my best to explain this.

Basically, I am loading a library through reflection using the Assembly.LoadFile.

From there I have an interface IFace that defines a method "GetStrings" that returns an array of strings.

The dynamically loaded DLL has a class named "Class1" that implements IFace.

I need a way to call this interfaced method through the dynamically loaded lib.  I'd like to keep it tightly coupled, which leaves me wondering what to do.  I know I can use MethodInvoker to call the method, but I'm trying to find a way I can do something like this:

```
IFace obj = (IFace)ReflectionAssembly.Class1;
string[] strs = obj.GetStrings();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If it's a static class, how can it implement an interface?

Comment: Sorry it's not a static class, GetStrings returns static array of strings.  My Bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like:

```
    var assm = Assembly.Load("ClassLibrary1");
    var type = assm.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Class1");
    var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type) as IFace;
    string[] strings = instance.GetStrings();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use Assembly.CreateInstance() to create the object, pass it a 'well known name'.  Cast the return value to IFace, the rest is easy.  Oh, don't use LoadFile, use LoadFrom.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have the Type via Reflection (using something like [Assembly.GetType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx)), you can use [Activator.CreateInstance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wccyzw83.aspx):

```
IFace obj = (IFace)Activator.CreateInstance(class1Type);
string[] strs = obj.GetStrings();
```